# Eigenvalues 3x3 Matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The following is a old exam, question. I did the calculation three times and every time I end up with eigenvalues $2$ and $6$, not $-2$. Normally wrong questions are corrected or removed, so because this one is still up, I doubt if I did anything wrong.

$$
A =\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0 & -4\textbf{i}\\ 
0 & 6 & 0\\ 
4\textbf{i} & 0 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Show that $−2$ and $6$ are the only eigenvalues of $A$ and determine the corresponding eigenvectors.

Comment: How do you get 2 and 6?

Comment: Did you check your result using ${\rm Tr }A=\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3$ and $\det A = \lambda_1 \lambda_2 \lambda_3$?

Comment: If $2$ were an eigenvalue, then $A-2I$ would have determinant zero, which it clearly does not. But $A+2I$ does have determinant zero, so $-2$ is surely an eigenvalue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try to calculate the eigenvalues together. They are the zeros of the characteristic polynomial, which, in this specific case, is:
$$\begin{align*}p_\lambda(A):&=\det\left(A-\lambda I\right)\\&=\det\begin{bmatrix}
2-\lambda & 0 & -4\textbf{i}\\ 
0 & 6-\lambda & 0\\ 
4\textbf{i} & 0 & 2-\lambda 
\end{bmatrix}\\&=_\blacktriangle(6-\lambda)\det\begin{bmatrix}
2-\lambda & -4\textbf{i}\\ 
4\textbf{i} & 2-\lambda
\end{bmatrix}\\&=(6-\lambda)\left[(2-\lambda)^2-16\right]\\&=(6-\lambda)\left(\lambda^2-4\lambda+4-16\right)\\&=(6-\lambda)\left(\lambda^2-4\lambda-12\right)\\&=(6-\lambda)(\lambda-6)(\lambda+2)\\&=-\left(\lambda-6\right)^2(\lambda+2)\end{align*}$$
where in $\blacktriangle$ we have used the [Laplace formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion) for the determinant. Hence we can easily see that the eigenvalues of the matrix $A$ are $-2$ and $6$, as desired.

Answer (score 1):

The characteristic equation of this matrix is given by $\det \begin{bmatrix}2- \alpha&0&-4\textbf{i}\\0&6 -\alpha&0\\4\textbf{i} &0&2- \alpha\end{bmatrix} = 0
\\ \implies (2- \alpha)(6- \alpha)(2- \alpha) - 4\textbf{i}(\alpha - 6)4\textbf{i} = 0
\\ \implies (\alpha-2)^{2}(\alpha-6) - 16(\alpha-6) = 0
\\ \implies (\alpha-6)\left[(\alpha-2)^{2} - 16\right] = 0
\\ \implies (\alpha-6)\left(\alpha^{2} - 4\alpha - 12\right) = 0
\\\implies (\alpha-6)^{2}(\alpha +2) = 0$.

So $6$ is an eigen value with multiplicity two, and $-2$ is an eigen value of multiplicity one.